# FLUTTER - How do I update a database from a synchronous function in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqflite

I am trying to implement a database into my first ever Flutter app (a calendar app), and wanted to store some DateTime values in a SQFlite database. Since all CRUD operations are asynchronous, I assumed that they would work in regular synchronous functions. However, ever since I have added a line 'await LoadedMonthsDatabase.instance.insertDateTime(value);' to my lazy loading function for recurring events, the lazy loading has stopped working altogether from this one line, and I'm not sure why. I have tried putting the line in an external asynchronous function and calling it from inside the _onMonthChanged function, but that hasn't done anything to fix this. I am in high school and trying to finish my first Flutter app before school starts, so a quick response would mean the world. Thank you! The relevant code will be attached below -

Code begins -

```
_onMonthChanged(DateTime? notRequired) {
    DateTime value = DateTime(currentChosenDate.year, currentChosenDate.month);
    bool isAlreadyLoaded = loadedMonths.any((dateTime) =>
        dateTime.year == value.year && dateTime.month == value.month);

    if (!isAlreadyLoaded) {
      for (int i = 0; i < recurringEvents.length; i++) {
        DateTime dateCounter = value;
        while (dateCounter.month == value.month) {
          int weekday = dateCounter.weekday;
          bool isRecurringDay = false;

          if (weekday == DateTime.sunday && everySunday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          } else if (weekday == DateTime.monday && everyMonday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          } else if (weekday == DateTime.tuesday && everyTuesday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          } else if (weekday == DateTime.wednesday && everyWednesday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          } else if (weekday == DateTime.thursday && everyThursday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          } else if (weekday == DateTime.friday && everyFriday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          } else if (weekday == DateTime.saturday && everySaturday!) {
            isRecurringDay = true;
          }

          if (isRecurringDay) {
            eventsList.add(
              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                startTime: DateTime(
                  dateCounter.year,
                  dateCounter.month,
                  dateCounter.day,
                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                ),
                endTime: DateTime(
                  dateCounter.year,
                  dateCounter.month,
                  dateCounter.day,
                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          dateCounter = dateCounter.add(const Duration(days: 1));
        }
      }
      addToLoadedMonths(value);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void addToLoadedMonths(DateTime value) async {
    debugPrint("addToLoadedMonths called with value of: $value");
    await LoadedMonthsDatabase.instance.insertDateTime(value);
  }
```

Comment: I'd use a Set of weekdays, rather than all that repeated code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! How exactly would I implement a set and use it?

Comment: Asynchrony is contagious: a function that needs to wait for another asynchronous function is inherently also asynchronous.  If you have asynchronous functions and want callers to be able to wait for them to complete, those asynchronous functions must return `Future`s that the callers `await`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Future<void> addToLoadedMonths(DateTime value) async {
    debugPrint("addToLoadedMonths called with value of: $value");
    await LoadedMonthsDatabase.instance.insertDateTime(value);
  }
```

and then:

```
Future<void> _onMonthChanged(DateTime? notRequired) async {
...
      await addToLoadedMonths(value);
      setState(() {});
}
```

this does not guarantee the correct code work, since it is not known how and when the _onMonthChanged function is used.

The main difficulty here is asynchronous work. You definitely need to get familiar with the basic dart concepts: future, await, async:

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

I'm sure even a quick glance will suffice for this case. Good luck!

p.s. but after the successful completion of the work also with the basis of [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)